# When is a one-sided test used versus a two sided test in a Fisher's Exact Test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

Suppose I have a 2 by 2 table and I am trying to conduct a Fisher's Exact Test. I am wondering when the two-sided test is used versus a one-sided test. In programs like `R`, they have `greater`, `less`, and `two-sided`. In most cases, I would only use either greater or less depending on the direction. However, when is the two-sided version ever used? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a very strong assumption **before** exploring your data that the values of one group will be either lower or equal to the other group (`alternative="less"`) or that the values of one group will be either higher or equal to the other group (`alternative="greater"`) you can use a one-sided test to increase the power of this test:

A two-sided test:

> If you are using a significance level of 0.05, [...] .025 is in each
>   tail of  the distribution of your test statistic [...] you are testing
>   for the possibility of the relationship in both directions.  [...] The
>   mean is considered significantly different from x if the test
>   statistic is in the top 2.5% or bottom 2.5% of its probability
>   distribution, resulting in a p-value less than 0.05.

A one-tailed test:

> When using a one-tailed test, you are testing for the possibility of
>   the relationship in one direction and completely disregarding the
>   possibility of a relationship in the other direction. [...] A
>   one-tailed test will test either if the mean is significantly greater
>   than x or if the mean is significantly less than x, but not both.
>   [...] The one-tailed test provides more power to detect an effect in
>   one direction by not testing the effect in the other direction. A
>   discussion of when this is an appropriate option follows.

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-the-differences-between-one-tailed-and-two-tailed-tests/